# How does Hadoop split files?

Tags: hadoop

I would like to know how the files are split in Hadoop. I mean, i know they are split by some size (e.g. 64MB), but does the break occur, at the end of a line or at some character etc?

Also how does the name node keep track of the sequence in which the files are split, like how to assemble them in which order after they are collected from the data nodes.

Answer (score 1):

*LineRecordReader* reads every line and sends key/value pairs to mapper instance. 
If EOL appears before defined block size(in this case 64MB), reader continues to next line.
Now, If reader reaches block size and not EOL, then it continues to read until EOL and set as a block.
Now, next block starts from where reader stopped(i.e., after EOL).

[Reference](http://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/understand-recordreader-inputsplit/)

Comment: What is the limit to which the block size is extended in that case, i.e. when EOL is not reached